# Uncaught ReferenceError: CommonFunctions is not defined(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two external javascript files, one called CommonFunctionsJS and the other called DealerCreateOrderJS.

The DealerCreateOrderJS is called in a view.

When I try to call a function from CommonFunctionsJS in the DealerCreateOrderJS, I keep getting an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CommonFunctions is not defined(…)

when I try to do this

```
$('#txtDate').val(CommonFunctions.GetCurrentDate());
```

in the DealerCreateOrderJS script

and am not sure why I would be getting this error, and not sure how to define it properly.

This is what the CommonFunctionsJS file looks like thus far

```
var CommonFunctions = {
    GetCurrentDate: function () {
        var dt = new Date();
        var currentDate = (dt.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getFullYear();
        return currentDate;
    }
}
```

I have added a reference to the view that references the DealerCreateOrderJS, but to no avail

**Adding HTML**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<style>
    /*#panelbar .k-state-selected {
        background-color:blue;
        border-color:blue;
    }*/

    /*#panelbar .k-state-focused .k-state-active {
        background-color: blue;
    }*/
    .k-numerictextbox .k-input {
    margin: 0;
    height: inherit;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="height:800px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="panelbar">
                <li>
                    Customer Information
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <br />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtFarmName" class="control-label col-md-2">Farm Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="txtFarmName" class="form-control" placeholder="Farm Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerName" class="control-label col-md-2">Customer</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerName" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAddress1">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="address" placeholder="Address 1" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="Address2" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationManufacturerAddress2">Address2</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Address 2" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtCity" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">City</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="City" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtState" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblState">Province</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <input id="txtState" type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="Province" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="txtPostal" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblZip">Postal</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <input id="txtPostal" type="text" class="form-control" name="postal" placeholder="Postal" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="acCountries" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCountry"><b>Country</b></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <select id="acCountries" class="form-control" name="country"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtPhone" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">Phone</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="Phone" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtNamePlate" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">Name&nbsp;Plate</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtNamePlate" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="Name Plate" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtLocation" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">Location</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtLocation" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="Location" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--Keep everything in here -->
                        </div><!-- End of Form Horizontal -->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="k-state-active">
                    Dealer Information
                    <div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtDealership" class="control-label col-md-2">Dealership</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtDealership" class="form-control" disabled />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtLocationName" class="control-label col-md-2">Sales Person</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtSalesPerson" class="form-control" disabled />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtDate" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModel">Date</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtDate" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtSalesRep" class="control-label col-md-2">Sales Rep</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtSalesRep" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dealer Sales Rep" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtSalesAdvisor" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModel">Sales Advisor</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtSalesAdvisor" type="text" class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Sales Advisor" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtPartNumber" class="control-label col-md-2">Part #</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtPartNumber" type="text" class="form-control max-size" disabled />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtContactEmail" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input id="txtContactEmail" type="text" class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Contact Email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="btn-group  col-md-offset-2" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancel </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/DealerCreateOrderJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the order of including JS files ? Paste html.

Comment: @mitch, i added the html, I DID have the CommonFunctionsJS referenced  in it right after the views own script, but I removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html is complete, you have not including JS file. Add
`<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/CommonFunctionsJS.js"></script>`
Before `<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/DealerCreateOrderJS.js"></script>`